# Sort all arrays inside object by another arrays with dates

Tags: javascript

I have object like this:

```
const test = {
  data1: ["3", "2", "1"],
  data2: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"],
  date: ["2021.01.01", "2022.02.02", "2023.03.03"],
};
```

I know how to sort the date array itself. But how to make the order of test.data1 and test.data2 also change after sorting the dates?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using objects?

Comment: It is already sorted. Isn't

Comment: You like to sort by?

Comment: Can you post what you had tried till now? So that we can help you where you are stuck

Comment: Sort ascending or descending by date. And sort all at once.

Comment: @oakpep what is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output when sorting ascending: `const test = {
data1: ["1", "2", "3"],
data2: ["dolor", "ipsum", "lorem"],
date: ["2023.03.03", "2022.02.02", "2021.01.01"],
};`

Answer (score -4):

Check [sandbox](https://playcode.io/826963)

```
const test = {
  data1: ["3", "2", "1"],
  data2: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"],
  date: ["2021.01.01", "2022.02.02", "2023.03.03"],
};
var test1 = test.data1.sort();
var test2 = test.data2.sort();
console.log(test1, test2)
```

Modifications:

```
function sortByDate(a, b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
var test = {
  data1: ["3", "2", "1"],
  data2: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"],
  date: ["2021.01.01", "2023.03.03", "2022.02.02"],
};

const sorted = test.date.sort(sortByDate);
console.log(sorted);
```

P.S. For advanced sorting you need to check [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Doesn't sort by date...